# Flutter FFMPEG Increases in processing time based on size of video even when only cutting the same size

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg, flutter-ffmpeg

I am by no means an expert with ffmpeg. But I'm finding it strange that the the time to create a gif and trim that section is increasing so much based on the size of the video **since I am always grabbing only three seconds.**

I am using flutter FFmpeg.

`-ss 0:00:01.000000, -i /data/user/0/com.example.example/cache/image_picker1475407716366431469.mp4 -t, 0:00:03.000000 -avoid_negative_ts make_zero, -vf fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse, -loop 0`

Is there a command to make sure that ffmpeg doesn't concentrate on the entire video, and only concentrates on the three seconds I am getting in -t, so that the time doesn't increase greatly based on the video size. Or is this just normal for ffmpeg. Does it have to parse the entire video, before creating the gif.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for anyone else looking. For some reason its much faster to just trim the original video and then make a gif. So just running `'-c:v copy '` on the original video and then running the above command cut the processing time on a 3 minute video down from 1 minute 40 seconds to 10 seconds.

Comment: Chris I've updated the gist from yesterday by adding some commentary and a neater version of `publishMessage1`, if you still care you know where to find it.